# nopcommerce 4.2 payment methods missing

Tags: paypal, payment, nopcommerce

I have NopCommerce source code and I cannot see any payment methods which used to come default with nopcommerce. It says download from [Marketplace](https://www.nopcommerce.com/marketplace.aspx?category=2&utm_source=admin-panel&utm_medium=payment-plugins&utm_campaign=admin-panel) but I cant find PayPal Standard plugin on the marketplace

In the root plugin folder I can see the plugin Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard which has some files. I believe this is a source code of the plugin. Then I can also see an empty folder of Payments.PayPalStandard

I can see the plugin in action on the demo nopcommerce site so I believe it is still relevant and available.

Am I missing something? Where can I find the plugin and how can I install it on my application

Answer (score 0):

Please download no source code from github.

Refer [this](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/releases/) link for download deployed code.

It's not possible that any payment plugin not there into plugin folder.

So please dowload from given link and check there are many payment plugins inbuilt.

Currently I have downoad **nopCommerce_4.20_NoSource_SelfContained.rar** and checked  **Payments.PayPalStandard** is there.

Answer (score 0):

Docs:

> `\Plugins` is a Visual Studio solution folder that contains plugin projects. Physically it's located in the root of your solution. But plugins DLLs are automatically copied in `\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\` directory which is used for already deployed plugins because the build output paths of all plugins are set to `..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\{Group}.{Name}\`. This allows plugins to contain some external files, such as static content (CSS or JS files) without having to copy files between projects to be able to run the project.

You need to build the project Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard, to publish the binary files in the output directory of `\Presentation\Nop.Web` project. Then run the project and complete the installation process of the plug-in in the administrative panel.